# Nothing happens when I click UISearchBar in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I added a UISearchBar to my initial UIViewController and everything works fine. However when I go to add the same UISearchBar, the same way to another ViewController that's pushed ontop of the first one, nothing seems to happen when I click into the searchBar. No delegate method is fired, no keyboard comes up, nothing.

This is how I'm adding it to the navigationBar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;



    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Search, eh?", nil);

    // Include the search bar within the navigation bar.
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;


}
```

Like I said it works in the first UIViewController, am I missing something in the other 2-3 viewControllers I've tried adding this too? I don't see why the searchBar shows up in the navBar but nothing is happening upon clicking into it. I've also set the delegate like so:

```
@interface ViewController () <UISearchResultsUpdating>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting `definesPresentationContext` to `NO` on the first view controller as soon as you present a new one on.

I believe that the presentation walks up the view controller hierarchy  looking for the first one that defines a context and not down.

Comment: Works great now. I suppose I just need to familiarize myself with definesPresentationContext, as I still am quite confused on what that line actually does. It seemed the searchBar was the only thing not working on the other views, but everything else seemed to work fine.